# Multiple relationships on a table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, database-design, ef-code-first

SQL Server 2012 MVC3 EF4.3.1 Code First project.

I have a `Teacher` and `Student` table with a one to many relationship. The `Teacher`’s tables `Id` will be used as the account number so its `Id` numbering needs to be separate from the `Student`’s. I would like to create a `Person` table (containing shared properties such as `First, Last, Phone, Email`) to reduce redundancy on the properties. `Person` will also have a one to many relationship to an `Address` table.

I’ve thought of trying a Table per Hierarchy model with `Teacher` and `Student` inheriting from `Person` but then the Id sets would not be separate and I would have to have a one to many relationship internally on the `Person` table. I could generate the ID’s through code but is an internal one to many doable or practical?

Another scenario would be to setup `Person` as a child table with a one to one between and `Teacher` and `Person` and a one to one between `Student` and `Person` but I’m not sure how or if it’s possible to have two separate one to one’s on a table.

Is there a practical way to do what I want or should I not worry about the redundancy and not use a `Person` table? If I went that route would it be possible to have two separate one to many relationships to an `Address` table (`Teacher-Address` and `Student-Address`)? Or for that matter a one to many (`Teacher-Address`, teacher may have an additional shipping address) and one to one (`Student-Address`)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do a Person table with an IsTeacher flag.

Comment: I am glad it worked out for you. You should post your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is to have a one to one between a `Person` and a `Role` table.  `Teacher` and `Student` are merely roles in this arrangement.  A given `Role` can be fulfilled by many `Person` instances.

Comment: duffymo would you have a link to a good article/s implementing Role Tables in this sort of scenario?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possibilities:

One: Go with your Student and Teacher inheriting from a base table of Person and not worry about the 'redundancy'. It's not a redundancy because your relating a Student and a Teacher not a Person to a Person and so in your database and DOM the Person table and Person class know nothing of the Teacher to Student relationship, it only knows that its a person. The teacher and student relationships are stored in there respective types, not the person type. Also, look at Table per Type instead of Table per Heiarchy. It's much cleaner and crisper looking in the database and you don't get all the information of each type in the heiarchy in one table.

Two: Create a table that specifically holds information that both Students and Teachers share and have that related to both the Student and Teacher table separately. You could call it something like "ContactInformation".

Answer (score 0):

Being a teacher and being a student are roles of people, not types of people.
You should have a table for People, a table TeachCourse to say that a Person is the teacher of a course (which in some cases are multiple teachers), a table AssistCourse to say which persons are attending a class as a student. You might have people that teach a course and assist another course, and that wasn't properly modeled in your first version.

You can also create a ContactInformation or ShippingInformation table for People to specify all their data (Some people may have multiple phones, or emails to).